# How to creat and initialized an image with alpha channel in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code, but it doesn't work: (it create an image which is all black)

```
eqr.create(size,CV_8UC4);
eqr.setTo( cv::Scalar(255,255,255,0)) ;
cv::imwrite("test.png", eqr);
```

this is also did not work: it creates an image which is all white.

```
eqr.create(size,CV_8UC4);
eqr.setTo( cv::Scalar(255,255,255,255)) ;
cv::imwrite("test.png", eqr);
```

What is the correct way to create an image with alpha channel and set all of its pixels to transparent?

Comment: You just did! A fully transparent picture is black and a non-transparent picture is white when (r,g,b)=(255,255,255)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find similar kind of example here

And if you need load transparent image(with alpha) use

imread("map.jpg",-1)

instead of

imread("map.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)

which will load alpha, See OpenCV Doc for more info.

Comment: Does jpeg images has alpha channel? Can you please provide link to documentation about passing -1 to imread?

Comment: @mans: he has just given example of image name and yes jpeg's revision supports alpha channel. Regarding doc for -1 for alpha, you can google or here is a direct link. I hope this helped :) http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#Mat%20imread%28const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20flags%29